# In flex, is there a way to capture and optionally cancel a row selection event in a DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

This should be trivial, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

I have a DataGrid, and what I would like to do, is when a user clicks on a row to select it, check a certain condition, and if it's met prevent the row from getting selected and keep the old selection intact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test it, but it should work using event.preventDefault() and/or event.stopImmediatePropagation() on the GridSelectionEvent.SELECTION_CHANGING event.

```
//stupid function but used for example purpose
private function addListener():void
{
    dataGrid.addEventListener(GridSelectionEvent.SELECTION_CHANGING, onSelectionChanging)
}


private function onSelectionChanging(event:GridSelectionEvent):void
{
    if(!canRowBeSelected(event.selectionChange.rowIndex))
    {
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}

private function canRowBeSelected(index:int):Boolean
{
    //add logic
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like what I want to do, but I don't see a GridSelectionEvent in the SDK. I am using 4.1, is this a newer feature?

Comment: I don't know since when it's there... are you using the Spark or MX one?

Comment: I tried both spark and MX. And as luck would have it, I can't load the adobe documentation to check.

Comment: Looks like the event for the spark grid has been introduced in Flex 4.5, can't find it in the 4.1 documentation